# DATABRICKS SQL/Python: Place string between first and second iteration only while using a for loop

Tags: python, sql, for-loop, pyspark, databricks

I have the following variable:

`x = 'PRD,MBP'`

I split the two on ',' in a for loop and then want to use the two new strings as dynamic inputs for select statements like so:

`for word in x.split(','): query = (""" SELECT * FROM word """)`

which should then return
`SELECT * FROM PRD SELECT * FROM MBP`

Now what I need is to add UNION between iteration 1 and iteration 2 so that it would look like this:
`SELECT * FROM PRD UNION SELECT * FROM MBP`

NOTE, the variable x can contain 1 string or more than 2. In case there is only 1 string I include  len(x) to derive the correct select string. So the solution should also be able to handle 3,4,5 strings.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction in achieving the above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
' UNION '.join(["SELECT * FROM {}".format(item) for item in x.split(',')])
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out @EvilX. Say I wanted to use your line without list comprehension how would I proceed? My current set-up uses the for item in x.split():. Within the for loop i then want to join multiple variables. E.g. (1) SELECT * FROM {PRD} (2) WHERE {PRD}.FIELDX = '1' etc The first iteration should have the PRD value passed in, the second iteration the MBP value. Both iterations should then be joined by UNION. Within the for loop I also test for x including only one string. Hence the reaason for not using list comprehension.

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer with an explanation.